# Delaying access to the server to try to avoid peak hours

Tags: java, algorithm, optimization, bandwidth

A JAVA 7 offline software used by thousands automatically sends a backup to the cloud when the users run it in the morning. Each sent backup consumes server bandwidth. See the chart below:

[image]

It can be noticed that a peak forms between 08:15 AM and 09:45 AM. This is because most users run the software between this time interval.

We need to change the software so it will send a backup to the cloud every 10 minutes. This will greatly increase bandwidth consumption and we are afraid that we will reach some limit because many users run the software at the same peak time.

As a workaround, we plan on randomly postponing the first backup to the server. However, we are not convinced that it is a good solution.

**Is this type of problem common? Is there any standard solution for it?**

---

*Here is the algorithm of how we are thinking of doing it, but we are not convinced that it is a good solution:*

```
new Thread(new Runnable(){                          
    @Override
    public void run(){

        String hhmmNow = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm")
                .format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());

        if( hhmmNow.compareTo("08:15")>=0 && hhmmNow.compareTo("09:45")<=0 ){
            Thread.sleep(new Random().nextInt(3600000)); //Sleep from 0 to 1h
        }

        while(true){
            sendBackupToTheCloud();
            Thread.sleep(600000); //Sleep 10 minutes
        }       
    }
}).start();
```

---

**EDIT:** *Changed to the following solution, according to Mcdowella suggestion:*

```
new Thread(new Runnable(){                          
    @Override
    public void run(){

        int periodicity = 10 * 60 * 1000;

        //Randon sleep between 0 and 10 minutes to 
        //distribute backups within the ten-minute interval.
        Thread.sleep(new Random().nextInt(periodicity));

        //Send new backup to server every 10 minutes
        while(true){
            sendBackupToTheCloud();
            Thread.sleep(periodicity);
        }       
    }
}).start();
```

Comment: what is the size of the backup that one app sends to the server?

Comment: The size of the backups varies between 500KB and 4MB.

Comment: okk if thousands of users are uploading backup to same server. you should consider using load balancers on your server. that way you won't need to change the algo in the software. or if you still have to implement then before uploading the backup to cloud you should request the server to get to know if enough bandwidth is available for you to upload. there are ways to check the bandwidth at server end through programatically

Comment: If you have logs that tell you when users upload backups for a particular day, you can use these to work out what the result of any particular sleep strategy would have been for that day. I would be inclined to always do a random sleep, but to make it a maximum of 10 minutes. Then each user is equally likely to pick any given timeslot within a schedule that repeats every 10 minutes.

Comment: @mcdowella You helped a lot with your comment. I did not use the logs, but the total size of backups stored currently, the average number of backups per user and the average that each user stay with the software opened along the day. Also, I will sleep between 0 and 10 minutes as you suggested. I got your point that I need to distribute the users within the 10 minutes interval. I understand the other's suggestions as well, but they are more complicated to implement and I don't have the necessary skills. I did the math and Mcdowella suggestion will be enough.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of different ways to solve this problem. You could do a slightly chatty protocol where clients first request to do a backup and wait for the server to response from the server allowing them to upload their data thereby allowing the server to queue certain clients when under high load.

One way to do this would be sending a 408 Request Timeout and then writing the client to try again after a delay.

Another idea would be to use an explicit [thread pool](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html) for handling requests so that there is a guaranteed limit on the number of clients being handled at any given time. Generally, most web servers will have a way of configuring this such as the [maxThreads option on Tomcat](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/config/http.html).

Randomization is probably not a good idea as suggested in the question because distributed systems tend to provide an extremely large sample size such that even seemingly rare events become inevitable.

Answer (score 1):

No good. Your delayed users from the beginning of the busy hour may end up being server at the highest point of the peak. Some users will be delayed even when there's no need.

While randomization flattens the peak a bit, it's surely no good idea. Simply asking the server if it can handle the request is simple and more effective. It doesn't need to be a separate request, the HTTP Status `503 Service Unavailable` is meant for exactly such a case. Your client should retry after a few minutes.

While a randomized distribution flattens the peaks, asking the server is the only way to perfectly constant utilization over time.

Note that your current bandwidth is below 1 Mb/s, which is *hundred times* less than what my IP provider offers for a *standard private home connection*. Your could use a load balancer or simply let the client choose from a pool of servers, if it's too much for one server. However, a single server should easily saturate the disk bandwidth which is something like 50 MB/s = 400 Mb/s for an old HDD.

Comment: You're right. The way I was thinking would end up with peaks of backups being sent at the same time. But if I follow Mcdowella suggestion I think it will help to distribute the backups well along the 10 minutes interval. I know it is not perfect, because there are different backup sizes and different bandwidth speeds of the users, but it will be enough. After all, according to my math, I will end up with an average of 9 MBps distributed.

Comment: Sure, but I'd recommend to ask the server, anyway, as it's much more future-proof. You may get 10 times as many users or multiple servers, some servers may fail... and asking them will always tell you what to do. `+++` Moreover, a randomized distribution still has some peaks and valleys, so your server won't be utilized perfectly.